# care-o-bot installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
When i tried to install package cob_apps, I have the following problem:
**rosdep install cob_apps
No installers found for rosdep [touchscreen], OS version [oneiric].  Rule:
{{{
{'10.10': 'xserver-xorg-input-evtouch', '10.04': 'xserver-xorg-input-evtouch', '11.04': 'xserver-xorg-input-evdev'}
}}}**
Please if you can help me to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31413/care-o-bot-installation/) by [Al-Moadhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2139/al-moadhen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-07**:
Please include more information, and include the actual errors you are seeing. http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [Al-Moadhen](https://answers.ros.org/users/2139/al-moadhen/) on 2012-04-07**:
Thank you for your replay. I use electric ROS version installed on ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cob_apps stack is deprecated. This means that there is no release for oneiric. The content of cob_apps was spread into cob_command_tools, cob_navigation and cob_manipulation.

---

Originally posted by [weisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1163/weisshardt/) with karma: 106 on 2012-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There does not appear to be a rosdep rule for oneiric defined in the rosdep.yaml.  You will need to add a rule for 'oneiric'.

Without knowing what version of ROS you are using I can't help point you the right file.  The [rosdep wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep) should get you started.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1